# How do I stop EF RIA services saving changes on related entities?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, silverlight, ria

Using RIA Services and EF5
EF model generated from Database.

I have a Parent object lets call it Class A.
Class A has a collection of ClassB's. ClassB has an instance of ClassC.

So on my view the user enters some data and the default workflow will produce a bucnh of ClassB's for them. However, they wish to be able to select which ones they will actually create.

So I create a wrapper holding the new ClassB item with a delegate to the actual action that will add the ClassB to Class A's collection.

So if the default is for Class A to have 2ClassB's but I deselect the first one and then action the required actions and save my changes I notice that my Class A's collection of ClassB's correctly contains only the one ClassB, but when I call SaveChanges on the context both diary items get saved.

What I've realised is that when  I add the ClassC to the ClassB, the ClassB is automatoically added to the Class Cs collection of ClassB's.

So when I call savechanges on the context, although I've only added the one ClassB to ClassA, both get saved because they have been added to ClassC

As ClassC only maps to what is essentially a lookup table we have no need to ever edit this or save changes, and we haven't implemented any CRUD functionality for it.

And while we have metadata classes for classA with includes for ClassB, and metadata for ClassB to include ClassC, there is no metadata class for Class C.

Any ideas how I can get around this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Use EntitySet's Remove function to remove the entities you don't want added to the database before calling SaveChanges, e.g.

```
dim context as new MyDomainContext
dim a as New ClassA
dim b as New ClassB
b.ClassA = a
context.ClassB.Add(b)     'Both a and b are added to the context
context.ClassA.Remove(a)  'Remove just a from the context
context.SubmitChanges()   'Submit only b
```